# php string extraction problem

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a string containing values i.e.

```
'Acton $ 80 Ajax $ 80 Aldershot $ 80 Alliston $ 115 Alton $ 80 Aldershot $ 84 Alexandria $ 674'
```

I want to make:

```
<option value='80'> Acton </option>
<option value='80'> Ajax </option>
```

...and so on.  How should I do this, using PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working code:-**

```
<?php
$str = 'Acton $ 80 Ajax $ 80 Aldershot $ 80 Alliston $ 115 Alton $ 80 Aldershot $ 84 Alexandria $ 674';
$arr = explode(" ", $str);
?>
<select>
    <?php 
    $i = 0;
    foreach($arr as $key=>$value) {
        if($i == $key) {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $arr[$i+2] ?>"><?php echo $arr[$i] ?></option>
            <?php
            $i = $key+3;
        }       
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
$str = 'Acton $ 80 Ajax $ 80 Aldershot $ 80 Alliston $ 115 Alton $ 80 Aldershot $ 84 Alexandria $ 674';
$arr = explode(" ", $str);
for($i = 0; $i < count($arr)/3; $i+=3)
    echo "<option value='".$arr[$i]."'>".$arr[$i+2]."</option>\n";
```

Try explode function. However, this code doesn't handle error input.

Comment: the code seems to work ok but nothing appears arr[$i+2] only the option value is there after so many blanks

Comment: Can you describe youre problem more specifically?

Answer (score 1):

```
$tmp = explode(' ', $string);

$result = '';
while (!empty($tmp)) {
  $name = array_shift($tmp);
  $dollarSign = array_shift($tmp);
  $value = array_shift($tmp);

  $result .= "<option value='$value'>$name</option>";
}
```

Comment: takes ages to process and timeout error appears on the browser

Comment: Except two annoying, but obvious typos: Not reproducable. Its works fine for me.